# Nested javascript callback functions

Tags: javascript, callback

Can someone explain why this works (i.e. delay 1 executes before delay 2):

```
function testCallBack() {
    one(two);
}

function one(callback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert("delay 1");
        callback();
    }, 2000);
}

function two() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert("delay 2")
    }, 1000);
}

testCallBack();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z71gkpfg/

but this doesn't (delay 2 somehow executes before delay 1):

```
function testCallBack() {
    one(two(three));
}

function one(callback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert("delay 1");
        callback();
    }, 3000);
}

function two(callback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert("delay 2");
        callback();
    }, 2000);
}
function three(){
     setTimeout(function () {
        alert("delay 3");
    }, 1000);
}
testCallBack();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/511nLm95/

Am I not nesting my callback functions correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a function reference to `one`.

So here the solution could be is to pass an anonymous function as the callback to `one` which will call `two` with `three` as the callback reference.

```
function testCallBack() {
    one(function(){
        two(three);
    });
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hh6bnhtL/)

Answer (score 2):

This line is causing your troubles:

```
one(two(three));
```

Here you don't just pass the function name of `two()` as a callback, **you actually execute the function** and pass the returned value.

You could rewrite the statement like this without changing the semantics:

```
var resultOfTwo = two(three);
one(resultOfTwo);
```

---

Instead, actually just use two as a callback:

```
function testCallBack() {
    one(two, three);
}

function one(callback, secondCallback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert("delay 1");
        callback(secondCallback);
    }, 3000);
}

function two(secondCallback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert("delay 2");
        secondCallback();
    }, 2000);
}
function three(){
     setTimeout(function () {
        alert("delay 3");
    }, 1000);
}
testCallBack();
```

Do you understand why this solution works?

Comment: Above answer is simpler